# Trouble with passing variable from one function to next?

Tags: wordpress, function, variables, global

I am trying to edit a plugin in wordpress that deals with a points system to suit my needs.  I have two functions, A and B.  Function A is basically telling the plugin to deal a different amount of points depending on a post term Id.  Function B is now trying to incorporate the variable $amount from Function A to limit users from ever going into a negative balance.  My problem is that I can't get Function B to get the $amount from Function A when determining its argument.  I tried to set it as a global variable but it didn't work.  Can someone suggest what would be the best approach for this?

In basic words, the plugin is set to always take 100 points from the user when
"dealing_points".  However, if the post term_id is equal to any of the below, then the amount of points changes.  Now I need the $amount in function B to always equal the new $amount that was calculated within the if condition when completing its argument.

```
function A( $run, $request ) {

if ( $run['ref'] == 'dealing_points' ) {

    // Original amount (Usually take 100 points)
    $amount = $request['amount'];

if(isset($_POST['term_id'])){

    if ($_POST['term_id'] == '74' )
        $amount = -50;

    elseif ($_POST['term_id'] == '75' )
        $amount = 50;

        $run['amount'] = $amount;

}         
}
         return $run;
}


function B( $reply, $request) {

if ( $reply === false || $request['amount'] > 0 ) return $reply;

extract( $request );

$user_balance = get_users_balance( $user_id, $type );


// Don't allow user to ever go below zero
if ( ( $user_balance + $amount ) < 0 ) return null;

return $reply;
}
```